# strange error--"seems that your device does not support camera.."

Tags: android, opencv, android-fragments, android-camera, android-videoview

i have created a `FragmentActivity` (VideoFragActivity) that holds a `VideoView`. along with that, i changed the FDActivity from the `OpenCV FaceDetection` sample code into a `Fragment` (FDFragment), and am trying to have that running during VideoFragActivity.

i stumbled across the following link while i was searching for help on StackOverflow:
[OpenCV's native camera in Android prevents video player from working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228904/opencvs-native-camera-in-android-prevents-video-player-from-working) but it is unanswered

my question is, **is it actually possible on Android to have the camera(initiated in a fragment) run during a fragmentactivity?** in my case, is it possible to have VideoFragActivity and FDFragment work so that a video would be playing while the opencv face detection sample runs?

**EDIT**

when I change the XML of FDFragment's height and width to either wrap_content, fill_parent, or match_parent, my app does not attempt to turn on the camera

HOWEVER when i change the height and width to random values (like 50sp or 100sp), it attempts to turn on the camera (calls `onCameraViewStarted()`), but gives me the error:

"It seems that your device does not support camera(or it is locked).Application will be closed"

i've checked that the permissions in my manifest are correctly placed and that the camera is not being used by another application. does anyone have ideas on how to approach this?

---

here is the code from FDFragment (please let me know if i changed the OpenCV Activity sample code into a fragment incorrectly):

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
             Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
             super.onCreateView(inflater, container,savedInstanceState);
         getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.face_detect_surface_view, container, false);
            return view;

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) getView().findViewById(R.id.fd_activity_surface_view);
            mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this); 

        }
```

...

```
 public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mGray = new Mat();
        mRgba = new Mat();
    }
```

permissions i added in the manifest:

```
    <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application   (...etc)
```

any help at all is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

update in case anyone is curious:

changed the way i approached this by having a fragmentactivity with an overall layout, and then added the mediaplayer as a fragment and the face detection as a separate fragment.

indeed,  you **CAN** have the camera running during media playback!